# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest what is considered an error?

Tags: ios

I am confused about this method, specially about the error part and the documentation. Here on the documentation it says that

> If the request completes successfully, the data parameter of the
>   handler block contains the resource data, and the error parameter is
>   nil. If the request fails, the data parameter is nil and the error
>   parameter contain information about the failure.

The problem is that, I have seen that some http response error codes fall into the "there is an error" and some dont, furthermore I can have data and error at the same time (but supposedly one should be nil at all times according to the documentation).

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest
                                       queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
```

For example, my server sends a 401 response if the user uses wrong credentials, and this is cached inside the error clause, but if i send a 409 (duplicate entry) this is NOT cached by it. Im having some issues redirecting the flow because of this, im not sure what this method will consider an error and what it will not.

Also, how do i properly check for this?, I thought that just checking if there is an error, and then checking what was the code of the response would suffice to display a message or take an action, but as I described before, some "error" codes don't necessarily generate the error object. Should i first check for the status code?

```
NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
int responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

if (responseStatusCode == 200)
{
    // If 200, assume everything went well?
} else
{
    // Something went wrong, check for the code and the error here?
}
```

Comment: Which status codes are you referring to? 200 isn't the only success code, and there are a good number of codes that could be returned. If you really need to get at details then use the delegate interface instead of the block interface.

Comment: im referring to the ones in the 400 - 499 range, these are all client side errors but only some generate an error. Also i don't see the difference of changing to the delegate interface.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience an error occurs when there is no response at all from the server, that's why the data is 0. If a server returns 400 or 500 error then these are a response from your server and depending on your server code maybe an error message you can parse.

Comment: Yeah but the issue is, why do only some error codes between 400 to 499 generate an error and others don't, where is the list of those that will?

Comment: From Apple's docs
`If the request completes successfully, the data parameter of the handler block contains the resource data, and the error parameter is nil. If the request fails, the data parameter is nil and the error parameter contain information about the failure.` My guess would be you're not handling the errors correctly server side, or as NSURLConnection is expecting.